# Constant rotation tween in Godot 4

Tags: c#, godot, tween, godot4

Godot's built-in `Tween` doesn't meet my requirements:

- It transitions a property's value given a *required* duration. The tween I want is constant; i.e., it increases with a constant speed. The linear transition doesn't fulfill my requirement.
- It transitions from a rotation angle to another not always going the shortest route: either counterclockwise or clockwise, depending on how far the angles are.

So I implemented a simple tweener for spinning a `Node2D` with a constant increment speed:

```cs
namespace Recoyx.CarKnockOnline.Util;

using Godot;

public class ConstantRotationTween
{
    public float IncrementDegrees;

    private Node2D _tweenNode = null;
    private bool _running = false;
    private float _incrementScale = 1;
    private float _targetDegrees = 0;

    public ConstantRotationTween(float incrementDegrees)
    {
        this.IncrementDegrees = incrementDegrees;
    }

    public bool IsRunning() => _running;

    public void Tween(Node2D tweenNode, float targetDegrees)
    {
        this._tweenNode = tweenNode;

        float a = 0;

        // keep target rotation between 0-360
        a = targetDegrees;
        a = a < 0 ? 360 - (-a % 360) : a;
        this._targetDegrees = Mathf.Round(a) % 360;

        // keep node rotation between 0-360
        this._lockTweenNodeRotation();

        a = this._targetDegrees;
        float b = this._tweenNode.RotationDegrees;
        float ab = a - b, ba = b - a;
        ab = ab < 0 ? ab + 360 : ab;
        ba = ba < 0 ? ba + 360 : ba;
        bool goClockwise = ab < ba;
        this._incrementScale = goClockwise ? 1 : -1;

        this._running = true;
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        this._running = false;
        this._tweenNode = null;
    }

    public void Process(double delta)
    {
        if (!this._running)
        {
            return;
        }
        this._lockTweenNodeRotation();
        if (this._tweenNode.RotationDegrees == this._targetDegrees)
        {
            this._running = false;
            return;
        }
        this._tweenNode.RotationDegrees += this.IncrementDegrees * this._incrementScale * ((float) delta);
    }

    /// <summary>Keep node rotation between 0-360.</summary>
    private void _lockTweenNodeRotation()
    {
        float a = this._tweenNode.RotationDegrees;
        a = a < 0 ? 360 - (-a % 360) : a;
        this._tweenNode.RotationDegrees = Mathf.Round(a) % 360;
    }
}
```

That's how you use it:

```cs
var tween = new ConstantRotationTween(150); // rotation speed = 150
tween.Tween(someNode, finalRotationDegrees); // starts a tween
tween.Stop(); // cancels the tween
tween.IsRunning();

// must be called in _Process
tween.Process(delta);
```

It almost works, just 2 issues:

- It may keep infinitely spinning the node or spinning it more than necessary to reach the final (target) rotation degree. This is due to the increment that is not equal 1.
- It has frame rate inaccuracy even when multiplying the increment by delta. I guess this is because I'm rounding the node's angle to an integer in `_lockTweenNodeRotation`.

It's almost two questions, but they're really simple and interconnected. So what can I do to  solve this frame rate issue and the unnecessary spins?

Or better, is there something in Godot for achieving the same with fewer lines of code?

---

I improved the above tweener as you can see in my answer, but the frame rate issue remains. Very little slight abrupt jumps during the object spin.

Answer (score 1):

A solution I found was to move the clockwise or counterclockwise route detection to the tweener's `Process()`. And if the route is too short (e.g. `delta < 5`), I assign the object's rotation to the final rotation and stop the tweener.

Unfortunately there are some *very little slight* jumps during the object spin. I'd appreciate help still.

Here's the working tweener:

```cs
namespace Recoyx.CarKnockOnline.Util;

using Godot;

public class ConstantRotationTween
{
    public float IncrementDegrees;

    private Node2D _tweenNode = null;
    private bool _running = false;
    private float _incrementScale = 1;
    private float _targetDegrees = 0;

    public ConstantRotationTween(float incrementDegrees)
    {
        this.IncrementDegrees = incrementDegrees;
    }

    public bool IsRunning() => _running;

    public void Tween(Node2D tweenNode, float targetDegrees)
    {
        this._tweenNode = tweenNode;

        // keep target rotation between 0-360
        float a = targetDegrees;
        a = a < 0 ? 360 - (-a % 360) : a;
        this._targetDegrees = Mathf.Round(a) % 360;

        this._running = true;
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        this._running = false;
        this._tweenNode = null;
    }

    public void Process(double delta)
    {
        if (!this._running)
        {
            return;
        }
        this._lockTweenNodeRotation();
        if (this._tweenNode.RotationDegrees == this._targetDegrees)
        {
            this._running = false;
            return;
        }
        (bool goClockwise, float routeDelta) = this._updateRoute();
        this._tweenNode.RotationDegrees += this.IncrementDegrees * this._incrementScale * ((float) delta);
        if (routeDelta <= 1.8)
        {
            this._tweenNode.RotationDegrees = this._targetDegrees;
            this._running = false;
        }
    }

    private (bool goClockwise, float routeDelta) _updateRoute()
    {
        float a = this._targetDegrees;
        float b = this._tweenNode.RotationDegrees;
        float ab = a - b, ba = b - a;
        ab = ab < 0 ? ab + 360 : ab;
        ba = ba < 0 ? ba + 360 : ba;
        bool goClockwise = ab < ba;
        this._incrementScale = goClockwise ? 1 : -1;
        return (goClockwise, Mathf.Round(goClockwise ? ab : ba));
    }

    /// <summary>Keep node rotation between 0-360.</summary>
    private void _lockTweenNodeRotation()
    {
        float a = this._tweenNode.RotationDegrees;
        a = a < 0 ? 360 - (-a % 360) : a;
        this._tweenNode.RotationDegrees = a % 360;
    }
}
```